# Unable to set Y Axis Interval On 2nd Chart Area

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've added a second chart area to my existing chart to show previous day's information. For some reason I cannot get the Y axis interval to set.

```
private void PreviousColorChart()
        {
            DatesTable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
            DatesTable.Columns.Add("SAT", typeof(string));
            DatesTable.Columns.Add("P4", typeof(string));
            DatesTable.Columns.Add("JUPIDU", typeof(string));
            DatesTable.Columns.Add("PSM", typeof(string));
            DatesTable.Columns.Add("SLDPRT", typeof(string));
            string FromDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
            string ToDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
            for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--)
            {
                DataRow row = DatesTable.NewRow();
                string Dates = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
                row[0] = Dates;

                for (int z = 1; z < DatesTable.Columns.Count; z++)
                {
                    string cmname = DatesTable.Columns[z].ColumnName.ToUpper();
                    string strr = "SELECT COUNT(_fileType) AS _Count FROM DFRFormingFileDelivery WHERE CAST(_ProgramProcessed as date) = '" + Dates + "' AND _FileType = '" + cmname + "' GROUP BY _FileType";
                    SQL sql = new SQL();
                    sql.ConnectToDB();

                    row[z] = sql.UpdateDatesTable(strr);

                }
                DatesTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            ChartArea CA1 = new ChartArea("PreviousColors");
            chart1.ChartAreas.Add("PreviousColors");
            chart1.ChartAreas["PreviousColors"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Interval = 50;
            chart1.ChartAreas["PreviousColors"].AxisY.MinorGrid.Interval = 10;
            chart1.ChartAreas["PreviousColors"].AxisY.MinorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
            chart1.ChartAreas["PreviousColors"].AxisY.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;
            chart1.ChartAreas["PreviousColors"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;

            string seriestitle;
            for (int c = 1; c < Form1.DatesTable.Columns.Count; c++)
            {
                seriestitle = Form1.DatesTable.Columns[c].ColumnName;
                chart1.Series.Add(seriestitle);
                chart1.Series[seriestitle].Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
                chart1.Series[seriestitle].ChartArea = "PreviousColors";
                chart1.Series[seriestitle].IsVisibleInLegend = false;
                chart1.Series[seriestitle].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                chart1.Series[seriestitle].CustomProperties = "LabelStyle=Bottom";
                chart1.Series[seriestitle].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
            }

            foreach (DataRow row in Form1.DatesTable.Rows)
            {
                if (row[1].ToString() != "0")
                {
                    chart1.Series["SAT"].Points.AddXY(row[0], row[1]);
                }
                if (row[2].ToString() != "0")
                {
                    chart1.Series["P4"].Points.AddXY(row[0], row[2]);
                }
                if (row[3].ToString() != "0")
                {
                    chart1.Series["JUPIDU"].Points.AddXY(row[0], row[3]);
                }
                if (row[4].ToString() != "0")
                {
                    chart1.Series["PSM"].Points.AddXY(row[0], row[4]);
                }
                if (row[5].ToString() != "0")
                {
                    chart1.Series["SLDPRT"].Points.AddXY(row[0], row[5]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've set the major interval to 50, and the minor to 10. But for some reason it isn't applying that when it produces the chart.

Can someone explain to me what it is that I'm doing wrong?
[Graph Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPqrB.png)

Comment: I'm not sure I even see a 2nd chartarea. shouldn't that `chart1.ChartAreas.Add("PreviousColors");` be `chart1.ChartAreas.Add(CA1);` ??

Comment: `chart.ChartAreas.Add()` will accept an item number, or string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I was headed the complete wrong direction. The intervals WERE setting properly.

What I was trying to change was the Y axis label interval. Which can be accomplished as so: `yourchartname.ChartAreas[yourchartarea].AxisY.LabelStyle.Interval = 25;`